# How can I combine ID from two tables after FULL JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have code like this:

```
SELECT ID, SUMof2016, SUMof2015
FROM      (SELECT ID, SUMof2016
           from table2016) t2016
FULL JOIN
         (SELECT ID, SUMof2015
           from table2015) t2015  on t2016.ID = t2015.ID
GROUP BY ID,SUMof2016, SUMof2015;
```

but this error shows up:

> ORA-00918 “Column ambiguously defined”
>   So I changed to like

```
SELECT t2016.ID, SUMof2016, SUMof2015
    FROM      (SELECT ID, SUMof2016
               from table2016) t2016
    FULL JOIN
             (SELECT ID, SUMof2015
               from table2015) t2015  on t2016.ID = t2015.ID
    GROUP BY t2016.ID,SUMof2016, SUMof2015;
```

But I assume that this does not show IDs of 2015, I would like show 2015 and 2016 IDs.

How can I show both 2015 and 2016 IDs withou getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `coalesce`, to get the first non-null `id`:

```
coalesce(t2015.ID, t2016.ID) as ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not need a `GROUP BY`.  Also, the subqueries are not needed:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2016.ID, t2015.ID) as ID, SUMof2016, SUMof2015
FROM table2016 t2016 FULL JOIN
     table2015 t2015 
     ON t2016.ID = t2015.ID;
```

If you want to see `0` instead of `NULL` for the ids that don't have values in both years:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2016.ID, t2015.ID) as ID,
       COALESCE(SUMof2016, 0) as SUMof2016,
       COALESCE(SUMof2015, 0) as SUMof2015
FROM table2016 t2016 FULL JOIN
     table2015 t2015 
     ON t2016.ID = t2015.ID;
```